# (C) malloc corrupted top size with random numbers

Tags: c, loops, random, malloc, calloc

So I'm trying to get an array of random 8-bit numbers of size *count* but I get the corrupted top size error whenever count is larger than 6. I read that it should be related to memory assignment but I can't figure out what is wrong exactly. I'm new to C so I'm not sure if the pointers are written correctly.

```
int *randBytes(int count) {

    srand(time(0));
    int *num = calloc(count, sizeof(uint8_t));

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        num[i] = (rand() % 255) + 1;
    }

    return num;
};

int main() {
    int randLen = 120;
    int *nums = randBytes(randLen);
    for (int i = 0; i < randLen; i++) {
        printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some 95% or so of all questions posted here about memory corruption when using malloc can be explained by incorrect parameters passed to malloc.

Comment: Ah, but I wasn't aware why it was wrong. I come from python so explicitly assigning types is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *num = calloc(count, sizeof(uint8_t));
```

You are allocating a buffer of size `count * 1` == `count`. If `sizeof(int) == 4` then the array can contain `count / 4` ints.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    num[i] = (rand() % 255) + 1;
}
```

You are then treating the array as an array of `count` ints, not `count / 4` ints.

---

You can fix this by either changing your `calloc`:

```
int *num = calloc(count, sizeof(*num));
```

or your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count / sizeof(int); i++) {
    num[i] = (rand() % 255) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `int *num = calloc(count, sizeof(int));`

Comment: `num = calloc(count, sizeof *num)` would be even more robust

Answer (score 1):

`int *num = calloc(count, sizeof(uint8_t));`

From the above line by doing a calloc you are a creating a memory of `count` bytes of type `uint8_t` and are using a `int*` to store and access the dynamically created memory.

And this happens to be the reason that you get corrupted data, when you dereference it to initialize each of the elements in an array you are dereferencing 4 bytes (32 bits) at a time, since the pointer is of the type `int` and  not `uint8_t` that would dereference 1 byte(8 bits) as per your requirement. Say your array count is 10 , you do create an array of 10 bytes but the for loop that does the initialization end up accessing 40 bytes causing the data corruption and might end up causing a segmentation fault due to invalid memory access(due to accessing memory that was beyond the bounds of 10 bytes that you had created).

You can make the following changes to your code for it to work fine

```
uint8_t* randBytes(int count) {

    srand(time(0));
    uint8_t *num = calloc(count, sizeof(uint8_t));

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        num[i] = (rand() % 255) + 1;
    }

    return num;
};

int main() {
    int randLen = 120;
    uint8_t *nums = randBytes(randLen);
    for (int i = 0; i < randLen; i++) {
        printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    }
}
```